# Express a vector as a combination of a linearly dependent set

Tags: linear-algebra

So I have to express the vector
\begin{pmatrix}
-2 \\
-4 \\
1 \\
0 \\
\end{pmatrix}

as a combination of these vectors:

\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
2 \\
1 \\
\end{pmatrix}

\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
1 \\
0 \\
2 \\
\end{pmatrix}

\begin{pmatrix}
-1 \\
-3 \\
4 \\
-4 \\
\end{pmatrix}

\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
2 \\
-1 \\
1 \\
\end{pmatrix}

But when I solved the augmented matrix, I got

\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 2 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & -3 & 0 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -3 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}

Meaning the system is linearly dependent. How should I go about expressing a linear combination without a linearly independent set?

Comment: Your reduced form of the augmented matrix (if your arithmetic is correct) shows that there are infinitely many solutions --- all you have to do is pick one.

Comment: Your free variable corresponds to the third column. Give it an arbitrary value (say $0$). Solve for the values of the other variables. (I'm assuming your augmented matrix is   correct).

Comment: I checked my work before and didn't get a linear combination, but I was using the wrong vectors. Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you can answer your question now, you can post an answer and then, after a while, you can accept your answer. This helps clear up the Unanswered Questions list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the following set of equations:

$$\begin{align}
a_1 + 2a_3 &= -1 \\
a_2 - 3a_3 &= 2 \\
a4 &= -3
\end{align}$$

There were infinitely many solutions. I set $a_3 = 0$ and got the following as a valid linear combination:
$$-v_1 + 2v_2 + -3v_4$$
I tried this and got a failing answer before, but it was because I used $v_3$ in place of $v_4$.

Comment: I see that there are infinitely many solutions. It would greatly improve your answer if you'd describe the solution that comes from "v3 = 0".

Comment: I added more explanation to the answer.